# 404 page vs. 404 server answer

Tags: 404, webserver, error

Could me somebody explain following topic:

On different sites i realized two scenarios, how not existing urls are handled. I'm not sure, which setup causes which scenario and which scenario should be preferred and why.

These scenarios are: on accessing of no longer existing url

- the url remains the same, but the page has the status code 404,
- an url changes to /404.html

Other differences are in what kind of 404 page is displayed. It can be a custom 404 page, which was setup with `Error Document`, otherwise it can be a default server 404 page or a default 404 page of CMS (if any in use).

The question is: which setup details cause the cases i listed above?

Answer (score 4):

**The TLDR; answer:** Send out a 404 header, don't change the url.

The longer answer:
There are more options then you suggest, which I'm not going to list here (because it's not really needed).

The most basic solution is just to serve a 404 header when the page does not exist. The reason for this is simple; This is what visitors expect. You open a URL and that either works or it doesn't.

Redirects to other pages are possible, but this should only be done when there is relevent content on the new page (do not redirect everything to home!). A better solution would be a custom page, with a few suggestions for your visitor, along the lines of:

"Oops! Page not found. Maybe you're looking for X, or perhaps Y? You can also go to Home"

Comment: @MrWhite per your comment, do you see any issues with a 404 response on the second (redirected) request? I'm trying to determine if a page that no longer exists that has a 302 to 404 makes sense. Thanks

Comment: Dont 302 to a 404. Just instantly do a 404. It's the first page that doesnt exist, so the first page should do that

Comment: @RobT I covered the "issues" with this approach in [my answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/104850/1243).

Comment: @Martijn I agree the straight 404 would be best but I think this site's webmaster is using this method when items go out of stock, as if trying to indicate to crawlers "hey this is a temporary 404". So just looking for a reason why this is bad practice.

Comment: @MrWhite if I am interpreting your answer correctly, it sounds like "as long as it ends in 404 you're good", but I don't get why someone would 302 to 404 vs 301 to 404

Comment: @RobT Maybe the webmaster is constrained by some CMS? Maybe they've made a mistake in implementation? As stated in my answer, if you specify an absolute URL in the `ErrorDocument` directive then Apache will implicitly trigger a 302 to the error document (but 9/10 times this is probably an error). "hey this is a temporary 404" - a 404 can already be perceived as temporary (a "410 Gone" is permanent). Search engines won't immediately drop those URLs from the SERPs and will continue to crawl those URLs for a long time to come.

Comment: @RobT "why someone would 302 to 404 vs 301 to 404" - 301s are cached by the browser by default, so this would be bad if you have any intention of bringing the URL back in the future. "when items go out of stock" - If there is any intention to restock those items then redirecting sounds like a bad idea - what if a user wants to bookmark the URL and monitor when the product is back in stock? If it's redirected, they can't (and nor can they read information about the product). Redirecting would only make sense if it was permanent - but then why redirect?

Comment: @RobT One "reason" might be to try and reduce the number of 404s reported in GSC - maybe? But even if that "works", it's not a good reason.

Comment: @MrWhite thank you so much for taking the time to address my questions and providing additional detail. You are correct it's a workaround. Here's what the developer said:
"Correct, the 200 respond will redirect to a 404. It is a work around due to the router.  
The 404 not found is when the page does not exist. However, when you searching some pages, those pages/page urls do exist due to the dynamic routers structure -  As serverName/shop/:param1?/:param2?/:param3?/
Only non-existing routers/url will response as 404 pages."
Any other tips to send or should I say the solution is adequate?

Answer (score 4):

> the url remains the same, but the page has the status code 404,

This is certainly the preferred option, as Martijn suggests. For a "custom" error page on Apache (ignoring the CMS option for a moment), this could be achieved with the `ErrorDocument` directive:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/my404.php
```

> it can be a default server 404 page

Using the `default` keyword clears any custom URL that might have been set and results in the servers default error document being served.

```
ErrorDocument 404 default
```

> or a default 404 page of CMS

Since a CMS is often serving pages defined in a database, it's not possible to use the `ErrorDocument` directive to handle 404s for pages defined (or not) in the CMS, since whether a request results in a 404 is only known much later in the request. The CMS detects that the requested URL does not exist and manually serves a `404 Not Found` header with some appropriate page content.

> an url changes to /404.html

For the URL to change there must be some kind of external *redirect*. Most probably a 3xx status code. To me, this would suggest a misconfiguration. The user-agent first sees the 3xx status code, not a 404. The document being redirected to may or may not then serve a 404 (it should). The user-agent ends up issuing 2 requests (because of the redirect). Providing the end-point returns a 404 status it is still effectively a 404.

Other caveats with issuing a redirect to the error document is that you lose the original URL (to provide a meaningful message to your user) and other details (server variables) related to the error. (This information would need to be manually passed somehow if it was required.)

There is rarely a *need* to redirect to a 404. On Apache, this is possible again with the `ErrorDocument` directive. If you specify an *absolute* URL (with protocol and hostname) as the error document argument then Apache issues a 302 (temporary) redirect (regardless of whether the URL actually resides on the same server):

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/errors/my404.php
```

This is primarily for redirecting to an external resource (should that be a requirement). But the same caveats with issuing a redirect apply, as mentioned above.

Comment: One other option is to edit the 404 page served by the web server. I used to do this with IIS and later with Apache. It is not a redirect to a 404 page, but the exact response page that the server will issue whenever a 404 error occurs. I personally like editing this file for a custom 404. However, the CMS that I wrote allows me to use any page as a 404 so that I can tailor the 404 error for the specific URL for maximum recovery. I rarely do this these days because I simply do not care anymore. ;-) However it is a valid idea for those who can do it. Cheers!!